# Room with Archmesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, windows

I created a room with archmesh, but when rendering with Cycles it´s dark inside, when rendering with Eevee I can see the outside through the window.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just add a light? Or increase the world light strength?

Comment: Your mesh isn't set up for physical rendering. There are no holes through which light can pass. The mock window works in Eevee only as an image of a window. That Sun can pass right through geometry and cracks in Eevee but not Cycles. I stuck a Point lamp in the skylight shape and Cycles began to light up. Make a real window hole, then use the Portal found in Cycle's Area lights (the check box won't show up in Eevee). Start with that, ask more if you need to! Welcome!